# Installed Moodle Font doesn't work in other browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts, moodle

I installed a moodle font (Coptic) in my Moodle Course and Theme and it displays correctly in Google Chrome. However when I try to view it in Firefox, I.E. or on my Tablet (Chrome via Nexus 9) it doesn't display the correct characters.

I followed these instructions before https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/How_to_add_custom_fonts_in_a_theme. The only thing is, before I only had Coptic.tff and no other font types. I.e. eot or svg. I then went online to get the other fonts. I.e. I uploaded Coptic.tff and got a zip of the other files. By including these other fonts in the dir. do you think it might fix the problem. Thanks for all you help. :-)

Comment: You'd need to share the relevant code so we can help you further.

Comment: What code do I need to share? Core CSS?  Style CSS?

Comment: At least сss code fragment in which you put this font.

Also try to clean moodle and browser caches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include all fonts type like you did.  Create a new directory in your theme and call it fonts. Then add all your custom fonts into this directory.
   eg: moodle/theme/yourtheme/fonts/

Some times " src: url([[font:theme|fontname.eot]]); ", this may not work.

Please add path like this

```
@font-face { /* where FontName and fontname represents the name of the font you want to add */
 font-family: 'fontname';
 src: url('../theme/your-theme-name/fonts/fontname.woff');
 src: url('../theme/your-theme-name/fonts/fontname.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../theme/your-theme-name/fonts/fontname.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../theme/your-theme-name/fonts/fontname.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../theme/your-theme-name/fonts/fontname.svg') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
```

}

Next ADD the name of your font wherever you want that font to be used in your stylesheet.
   For example:
   #page-header h1 { font-family: FontName;}

try !!! It will work for you :)

Comment: This is only a workaround, but not a solution for the problem. Why is it sometimes not working? How could one debug this issue?